# Django successful migrate but didn't create table on MYSQL

Tags: python, mysql, django, database-migration

Could anyone help me.

At first, I created a sqlite DB for my APP , but now need to migrate it into MYSQL.

In SQLITE all is working fine but when I migrated to MYSQL it's not creating the tables.

Thanks in advance for those who will help.

---

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class sslDomain(models.Model):
    domain = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
    expiration = models.TextField(max_length=50, default='')
    date_now = models.TextField(max_length=50, default='')
    status = models.IntegerField(max_length=50, default=0)
    daysleft = models.TextField(max_length=50, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.domain

class logsTable(models.Model):
    logs_field = models.TextField(max_length=100, default='')

    def ___str__(self):
        return self.id
```

---

auth_db.py(my DBrouter)

```
from .apps import *

class AuthSslDB:
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models in the
    auth application.
    """
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to read auth models go to auth_db.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == SsldomainsConfig.name:
            return 'argus_v2_db'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to write auth models go to auth_db.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == SsldomainsConfig.name:
            return 'argus_v2_db'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Allow relations if a model in the auth app is involved.
        """
        if obj1._meta.app_label == SsldomainsConfig.name or \
           obj2._meta.app_label == SsldomainsConfig.name:
           return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        """
        Make sure the auth app only appears in the 'auth_db'
        database.
        """
        if app_label == SsldomainsConfig:
            return db == 'argus_v2_db'
        return None
```

---

settings.py

```
'argus_v2_db': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'argus_v2',
    'USER': 'yrollrei',
    'PASSWORD': '****',
    'HOST': '*.*.*.*',
    'PORT': '*',
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['SSLDOMAINS.auth_db.AuthSslDB']
```

Comment: i used this.

./manage.py makemigrations SSLDOMAINS

./manage.py migrate --database=argus_v2_db SSLDOMAINS

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that  if i create new table that not came from sqlite, it's working.

my problem fixed by just cloning my class in models.py and i just renamed it.

hope it will works to others that have the same problem.